# Error spotting: The ten captains (A)/ had each an (B)/ achievement of (C)/ his own. (D)/ No Error (E)

Tags: grammar, articles, adjectives, nouns, error

Given answer in book is (E) "No Error".
But there is a rule in textbook that we can't use article before the noun which comes after "Each / Every / Each and Every / Either / Neither".
Can anybody help in understanding the answer?

Comment: Possibly the creator of the question is not a native English speaker.  .... ten captains **each had** an... is more natural. And I don't like the use of **his** and would say **their** because of the multiple captains.

Comment: The answer is correct, but the use of "his" assumes that all of the captains are male, which may not be true, (unless there is additional context not included here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no error. What is in error is the rule in your text book or your interpretation of the rule.

In the passage provided, the meaning is

> Each of the ten capitains had an achievment of his own.

Notice that "each" refers to "captains," and "captains" has a definite article associated with it. For emphasis, you may also say

> The ten captains each had an achievement of his own
>
> The ten captains had each an achievement of his own

although the second is very rare.

What is not rare is

> Each captain had an achievement of his own.

What all these examples share is that "each" refers to individual members of a group of capitains, not their individual achievements.

What you cannot grammatically say is

> Each the ten captains had ...

The rule is that if "each" precedes the noun **to which "each" applies**, it cannot be **immediately** followed by an article applying to the **same** noun. Moreover, that rule does not apply to "either" or "neither.

> Either the man or the boy can do it because each knows the password
>
> Neither the man nor the boy can do it because neither one knows the password.